# Sessions with Flask (python)

Tags: python, session, flask, secret-key

I'm on a project with Flask and I would like to create a session when the user is logging in. I follow the documentation but my script doesn't work and close directly after the opening. So, no way to launch my project in my browser.

My code is the following one:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, url_for, request, session
import mysql.connector
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/connexion/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def connexion():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['mail'] == "":
            return affichage_form_mail(erreur = "001")
        else:
            cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='admin', password='mysql', host='localhost', database='colocation')
            cursor = cnx.cursor()
            query = ("SELECT COUNT('email'), password FROM user WHERE email = '" + request.form['mail'] + "'")
            cursor.execute(query)
            i = cursor.fetchone()
            if str(i[0]) != "1":
                # on regarde le nombre d'enregistrements. Si diff de 0, on réaffiche le formulaire avec un code d'erreur 001
                return affichage_form_mail(erreur = "001")
            else:
                # on vérifie le mdp
                if request.form['password'] != str(i[1]):
                    # mot de passe faux, on reaffiche form_login avec en argument l'erreur et le mail
                    return affichage_form_mail(request.form['mail'], "002")
                else:
                    # l'user est connecté. On le redirige vers son compte et on met une variable dans la session
                    session['connect'] = True
            cursor.close()
            cnx.close()
    else:
        return affichage_form_mail()

def affichage_form_mail(mail='Adresse email', erreur='none'):
    aff_erreur = ""
    if erreur == "001" :
        aff_erreur = "Email inexistant"
    if erreur == "002" :
        aff_erreur = "Mot de passe inccorect"
    if erreur == "003" :
        aff_erreur = "Il faut indiquer email"
    return aff_erreur + '<form action="" method="post"><input type="text" name="mail" value= "' + mail + '" /><input type="text" name="password" /><input type="submit" value="Envoyer" /></form>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.secret_key = "dd"
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I know that my secret key is not so secure but it is not the point. Note that I tried without the secret key (don't ask why...) and I can open my project in Chrome but I have, of course, a error message telling that I have to put a secret key.

I hope you will be able to help me... I checked in the official documentation and I copy-paste to be sure to avoid any mistake but it still not working.

Comment: Run your script from an already-open command line so you see any errors that might occur. Also, the code you posted is far from complete.

Comment: I edited my question with the complete code :)

Comment: Now tell us what error you get when running the file in a terminal where you see the output.

Comment: I don't see anything... My terminal closes automatically and no way to read the error message :s

Comment: If you open it first and *then* execute `python yourfile.py` in there it should stay open. Otherwise you need to fix your terminal problems first. Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: Ok... I found. My error was just that there was four spaces and not an indent on the last line... Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok, please consider deleting the question as it has zero use for further users. And please fix the issues I mentioned (sql injection, templating).

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation of `app.secret_key = "dd"` is wrong. It must be on the same level as the `app.run` call.

Indentation is NOT OPTIONAL in Python - it's part of the syntax. You MUST indent blocks in a consistent way or your script won't run.

Python gives you *very* helpful error messages by the way - so please run your code in a terminal (cmd.exe on windows, any shell on other OSes) using `python yourfile.py`. That way the terminal does not close when the script terminates and you actually see errors instead of having to ask here.

---

Also you handle SQL really wrong:

```
query = ("SELECT COUNT('email'), password FROM user WHERE email = '" + request.form['mail'] + "'")
cursor.execute(query)
```

That code has a gaping SQL injection hole. Do this instead:

```
query = "SELECT COUNT('email'), password FROM user WHERE email = %s"
cursor.execute(query, [request.form['mail']])
```

This way the database (or database api) will handle your arguments in a secure way.

---

Another thing: You should really use Jinja2 templates instead of creating an ugly mess of embedded HTML. It's an excellent template engine that's already a dependency of Flask anyway.

Comment: Ok. Error by indenting in Stackoverflow. My apologizes. In my file, it is good.

Comment: Oh I see, you mixed tabs and spaces. Also something you should never do. Only use 4-space indentation!